# Get previous row from .loc

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe where `date` is used as index.

```
            close
date             
1999-11-18  44.00
1999-11-19  40.38
1999-11-22  44.00
1999-11-23  40.25
1999-11-24  41.06
```

Given an arbitrary date, I'd like to retrieve a row that is `n` places before or after that one.

For example:

```
df.loc["1999-11-22"] # Gives third row
df.loc["1999-11-22"].previous_row(-2) # Should give row 1999-11-18
```

Obviously `previous_row` doesn't exists. I've tried with `shift(-2)` but that doesn't seem to work: `date` remains the same and `close` becomes `NaN`.

```
df.loc["1999-11-22"].shift(-1)
close   NaN
Name: 1999-11-22 00:00:00, dtype: float64
```

Is there a simple way to do this that doesn't involve cloning the whole dataset?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`index.get_loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
In [11]: df.index.get_loc("1999-11-22")
Out[11]: 2

In [12]: df.iloc[df.index.get_loc("1999-11-22") - 2]
Out[12]:
close    44.0
Name: 1999-11-18, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `shift`

```
df.shift(2)[df.index=='1999-11-22']
Out[242]: 
            close
date             
1999-11-22   44.0
```

Answer (score 2):

I’d translate the index lookup to find out its positional index in the DataFrame’s index and then calculate the offset of that  positional index and lookup the corresponding value using iloc, which is the positional index API.

Comment: This is technically correct but is missing a very important detail: code.

Comment: Yep. I’m on mobile and it looks like Andy above did the right thing. I’ll delete this answer in a bit.

Comment: It's all right, I don't think the spirit of S.O. is necessarily "code stuff for me". A correct answer, even without code, is much appreciated and I think deserves to remain on the website (though I'll obviously accept the other one).