# pandas selecting rows for specific time period

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a pandas dataframe with date index. Like this

```
                  A         B        C
     date
  2021-04-22      2         1        3
  2021-05-22      3         2        4 
  2021-06-22      4         3        5
  2021-07-22      5         4        6
  2021-08-22      6         5        7
```

I want to create a new dataframe that selects rows that are only for 2 days previous for a given date. So for example if I give selected = '2021-08-22', what I need is a new dataframe like below

```
                  A         B        C
     date
  2021-07-22      5         4        6
  2021-08-22      6         5        7
```

can someone please help me with this? Many thanks for your help

Comment: 2 days or 2 months ...

Comment: Please refer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56247791/get-previous-row-from-loc). You can get the `iloc` of the row and the one before it with `index` and then print as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert convert the index to DatetimeIndex, then use `df[start_date : end_date]`

```py
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
selected = '2021-08-22'
res = df[(pd.to_datetime(selected)-pd.Timedelta(days=2)) : selected]
```

```
print(res)

            A  B  C
2021-08-22  6  5  7
```

Comment: thank you, this works. What would I have to do if I want the resultant df that is counting 2 days backwards from the selected date? So If I select 2021-08-22, I should get data for 2021-08-21 and 2021-08-20 (not 2021-08-22)

Comment: @user18334254 Maybe `df[(pd.to_datetime(selected)-pd.Timedelta(days=2)) : (pd.to_datetime(selected)-pd.Timedelta(days=1))]`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you meant *months* instead of *days*.

You can use the `df.apply` method in order to filter the dataframe rows with a function.

Here is a function that received the inputs you described and returns the new dataframe:

[Working example](https://abstra.show/ABfuNQ2fI1)

```py
def filter_df(df, date, num_months):
    def diff_month(row):
        date1 = datetime.strptime(row["date"], '%Y-%m-%d')
        date2 = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        return ((date1.year - date2.year) * 12 + date1.month - date2.month)

    return df[df.apply(diff_month, axis=1) > - num_months]


print(filter_df(df, "2021-08-22", 2))
```